# sharepoint 2013 storing data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

In my company, we are just starting to use sharepoint 2013. I have been assigned a 'protype' project that will be used by other workflow projects that will be setup in the future.

My question is about how the data is stored accessed and updated. I know that you can store the data in a sql server database and there is a service that can be setup for security purposes in Sharepoint 2013. My problem is the database and security have not been setup right now. I need to have this prototype setup before the DBA and sharepoint admin can setup the configurations for me.

Thus can you tell me and/or point me to a url that will tell me how to setup the storage for the lists I want to setup in sharepoint designer 2013?

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the steps in the article [Install SharePoint 2013 on a single server with a built-in database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202%28v=office.15%29.aspx) you are well on your way to make a good evaluation SharePoint Farm.

> You can quickly publish a SharePoint site by deploying SharePoint 2013 on a single server that has a built-in database. This configuration is useful if you want to evaluate SharePoint 2013 features and capabilities, such as collaboration, document management, and search. This configuration is also useful if you are deploying only a few websites and you want to minimize administrative overhead.

The installation doesn't require DBA support because you are using SQL Server Express, which is free to download, install and use.

When you have installed SharePoint on a single server, you can use SharePoint Designer to configure style, workflow, lists and libraries the way you want to.